# How to get Id name with jquery and pass to php script?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have been trying to get the id of a button(in this case a link) with jquery and send the id or class name to a php script so I can enter that id or class name in a sql query. I thought that this would be the easiest thing to do, but it has turned out to be the most difficult thing since nothing seems to work.

I have on one page a link:

**pagination.php:**

```
<a href="#" class="category" id="marketing">Marketing</a>
```

then another script for the jquery (when the button is clicked):

**jquery_pagination.php:**

```
$("#pagination a#marketing").click(function () {


    Display_Load();

        var pageNum = $('#content').attr('data-page');

        $("#content").load("filter_marketing.php?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());

        });
```

And lastly, the php page where I want the 'marketing' id to go:

**filter_marketing.php:**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$per_page = 3;
if($_GET)
{
$page=$_GET['page'];
}
$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
//$sql = "select * from explore order by id limit $start,$per_page";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM explore WHERE category='marketing' ORDER BY category LIMIT $start,$per_page";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table width="800px">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$msg_id=$row['id'];
$message=$row['site_description'];
$site_price=$row['site_price'];

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $msg_id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $message; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $site_price; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

So all I want is to automatically place the id of 'marketing' in the sql query instead of hard coded as seen here:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM explore WHERE category='marketing' ORDER BY category LIMIT $start,$per_page";
```

If anyone can help on this that would be amazing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really be more specifics than just saying "nothing works". Does the ajax call works? If not, it's probably a filepath. Heck, i might as well ask you if you're including jquery correctly.

Anyway, your serverside script is far from error-proof, so careful with that.

if all you want is to have the id sent to the script, try this (assuming your ajax code works);

```
$("#pagination a").click(function () {


    Display_Load();
    var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var pageNum = $('#content').attr('data-page');
    $("#content").load("filter_marketing.php?page=" + pageNum +'&id='+this_id, Hide_Load());
});
```

Then your serverside script:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$per_page = 3;

$page= ($_GET['page']!='') ? $_GET['page']: false;
$id= ($_GET['id']!='') ? $_GET['id']: false;

$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;


if($page && $id){
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM explore WHERE category='$id' ORDER BY category LIMIT $start,$per_page";
}
else
{
   die('Error: missing parameters. Id= '.$id.' and page= '.$page);
}


$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table width="800px">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$msg_id=$row['id'];
$message=$row['site_description'];
$site_price=$row['site_price'];

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $msg_id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $message; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $site_price; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#pagination a#marketing").click(function () {

var $linkElement = $(this);
Display_Load();

    var pageNum = $('#content').attr('data-page');

    $("#content").load(
      "filter_marketing.php?page=" + pageNum + '&id='+$linkElement.attr('id'),
       Hide_Load());
    });
```

Now the id of the clicked link will be supplied in the id-parameter.